# Dynamically use React components with strings

Tags: reactjs

Problem: How to dynamically use React components with strings

I am trying the first alternative on [this page](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9), but it does not work. Do anyone know why?

```
// inside a functional component
import CuteSvg from './svg/CuteSvg';
...
const MySvg = props.nameOfSvgToUse; // "CuteSvg"
return <MySvg />;
```

Comment: import cannot be executed dynamically

Comment: @linchong I am importing the imports as usual, and not dynamically. It is only the usage of the imports that are dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A name of a component is just a string, you should use it as a key to match the component, useful pattern is an object acted as a dictionary.

Also, read how to import SVGs as React components [in CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs).

```
import { ReactComponent as CuteSvg } from "./svg/CuteSvg.svg"; // if its an svg file
import DogSvg from "./svg/DogSvg.js"; // if its a component

const SVGS_COMPONENTS = { CuteSvg, DogSvg };

const Component = (props) => {
  const MySvg = SVGS_COMPONENTS [props.nameOfSvgToUse]; // MySvg is a function component
  return <MySvg />;
};
```

Comment: So the part `{ ReactComponent as CuteSvg }` will import a svg correctly?
Because now I wrap my svg inside a functional component, inside my ./svg/CuteSvg.js file, something like:

`const CuteSvg = () => <svg>...</svg>`

So when I do like you describe, I do not need to wrap my svg into a functional component?

Comment: Notice the suffix `.svg` if you wrap `svg` in a component just import it normally...

Comment: Yes, thank you!
But that means I could just skip the wrapping of my svg inside a functional component and just paste my svg inside a .svg file and import it like you do with `{ ReactComponent as CuteSvg }` and use it as a "normal React component". That seems much easier (just another way of import)

Comment: In both cases, you will have a single file, choose what fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import CuteSvg from './svg/CuteSvg';
import CuteSvg2 from './svg/CuteSvg';

const components = {
  CuteSvg,
  CuteSvg2
}

const MySvg = function(props){
  return components[props.nameOfSvgToUse]
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so I do need to add an object  with all the components? I was hoping I could skip that part and only use the strings :P But if that is what it takes! Thank you very much, I will try this out!